# Hover over image, darken background only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to be able to hover over an image and only the background itself to turn black (with opacity to control how much).  I already have have an effect for the image itself when it's on hover, but I would like to add an effect where the background which is white to turn to a darker color.  Being able to manipulate it later on with opacity and transition would be best, but I have not been able to find css3 or jquery code that works for this so far to get me to that point.  Any help would be appreciated.

html

```
<div class="template_design2" style="margin-top:100px; margin-left:5px;"></div>
```

css

```
.template_design2 {
    background-image:url(img/template_design2.jpg); 
    width:740px;
    height:280px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    float:left;
}

.template_design2:hover {
    background-position:0 -280px;   
}
```

Comment: Can you put your code into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Upload your image or find some example image somewhere that illustrates the same principles as your image (transparency etc.)

Comment: http://www.juliancelaj.com/designlayout.html

I don't know how to upload the images themselves, but here's my website link as an example.  Basically when it hvoers over the rectangular templates and it turns brighter, I'd like the background (which is completely white) to get darker.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a class to your `<a>`s that contain the background images, so you can target them.

You use `.template_design:hover`, so to target the first one (since it has no class, but you can use its ID to test it works quickly, then assign all `<a>`s inside `.template_design` a class so you can target them all at the same time):

```
.template_design:hover a#zapzonePoster { opacity: 0.5; }
```

Here's a fiddle showing how it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/v6aNY/

So once you know that's working, you could then assign a class so it would be more like:

```
.template_design:hover a.thumbnail { opacity: 0.5; }
```

... which will target all of them, so you only need one rule to govern it, instead of many.

Here's the same fiddle updated with a class of `.thumbnail`:

http://jsfiddle.net/v6aNY/1/